# CGPoint returning method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cgpoint

i try to return a CGPoint but i do something wrong:

Here is my method:

```
- (CGPoint)calculatePointOnCircleFrom:(CGPoint)pointA PointB:(CGPoint)pointB radius:(float)rd {
    float sryy = pointA.y - pointB.y;
    float srxx = pointA.x - pointB.x;
    float sry = pointA.y + sryy;
    float srx = pointA.x + srxx;
    float kpx = pointA.x + cos(atan2(pointA.y - sry, pointA.x - srx)) * rd;
    float kpy = pointA.y + sin(atan2(pointA.y - sry, pointA.x - srx)) * rd;

    return CGPointMake(kpx, kpy);
}
```

The code in the method works fine but i do something wrong with the initialization.

Here i call the method:

```
    point1.position = [self calculatePointOnCircleFrom:Player.position PointB:touchPos radius:64];
```

and get fooling error: "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setPosition:'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably also a warning that it can't find the method declaration. It sounds like the compiler doesn't know what type the method returns and is defaulting to id.

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely you'll see that the message is about an incompatible type for argument 1 of a method called **`setPosition`**, not the `calculatePointOnCircleFrom` method. The `setPosition` is the setter for the `position` property.

So the problem is with the `point1.position =` part of the line, not the call to the `calculatePointOnCircleFrom` method. I suspect the `position` property of the `point1` variable is not of type CGPoint since that's what the `calculatePointOnCircleFrom` method is returning.

Alternatively, you may not be calling the method you think you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is telling you that the type returned by `[self calculatePointOnCircleFrom:Player.position PointB:touchPos radius:64]` does not match the type of `point1.position`. Is `position` a CGPoint?

Comment: yes, i think so if i do: "point1.position = CGPointMake(200,200);" it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on a not perfect way but it works.

I return know a NSValue:

```
- (NSValue *)calculatePointOnCircleFrom:(CGPoint)pointA PointB:(CGPoint)pointB radius:(float)rd {
   float sryy = pointA.y - pointB.y;
   float srxx = pointA.x - pointB.x;
   float sry = pointA.y + sryy;
   float srx = pointA.x + srxx;
   float kpx = pointA.x + cos(atan2(pointA.y - sry, pointA.x - srx)) * rd;
   float kpy = pointA.y + sin(atan2(pointA.y - sry, pointA.x - srx)) * rd;

   return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(kpx, kpy)];
}
```

and call method like so:

```
NSValue *pos = [self calculatePointOnCircleFrom:Player.position PointB:touchPos radius:64];
CGPoint cgpos = [pos CGPointValue];
point1.position = cgpos;
```

Thanks for every ones help :D